# Find memory leak using Eclipse memory analyzer

Tags: android, memory-management, memory-leaks

I am working with an app which has a memory leak, after a while that user works with it. I could check that in DDMS using `heap` Tab by looking at Heap size and Allocated.

In the application user can always take an image using device Camera, draw on the image, and save it on the system.

By every record that user create in the system the allocated memory is increasing a little bit, and after a specific number of records memory leaks is happening.

I export the .hprof in DDMS, and convert it to [eclipse memory analyzer](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/) file unisg hprof-conv from Android sdk. 
I followed couple of link to see where the problem come from such as:

[Google I/O 2011: Memory management for Android Apps](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CruQY55HOk).

[10 Tips for using the Eclipse Memory Analyzer](http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2013/01/21/10-tips-for-using-the-eclipse-memory-analyzer/).

I still could not find the source of problem. This is the Mat.hprof file from SkyDrive : https://skydrive.live.com/#cid=2EB3385F103C2550&id=2EB3385F103C2550%21105

Could anyone look at this file and give me some hint, where the problem come from? or any suggestion for improvement?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to compare 2 hprof file in MAT ?

There is an option "Compare to another Heap Dump" in histogram view. It will show you the difference between 2 hprof file, and then it will be easier to find out your memory leak

Answer (score 0):

It's simple :

-Open your dump, and then use the dominator tree :
[image]

You can see 2 big object retained in the stack, one from Resources, and a Bitmap.
-Use the right click to show the shortest path to gc on the bitmap :

[image]

There, you can see the answer. In your app, you probably have a big image contained in your res folder. 
The problem is this could cause out of memory error when you're using this image in a layout directly. You need to load the bitmap programatically using this tutorial to avoid memory leak :

http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

Answer (score 0):

After I have load your .hprof file in MAT, I saw that your app creates a lot of arrays with nested collections inside from which OutOfMemoryError occurred. So what is the reason? To get back result in AutoCompleteTextView you are using Handler that probably may cause Memory Leaks, it can hold a strong reference on current views and your Activity ultimately. You should pay more attention to collections release process in time when life cycle events occur.